# Powershell Check if a User or Role is added to .Net authorization rules

Tags: xml, vb.net, powershell, iis

I am trying to automate the process of adding users or roles to .NET authorization rules.
I can successfully execute this command to add users and roles.

`.\appcmd set config 'Default Web Site/TestApp' /section:system.webServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',roles='Admin,Guest',users='User1,User2,User3']"`

But, I want to be able to check if the user or role is already added to the 'allow' rule before running above command.

When i run the 'list config' command:

```
.\appcmd list config 'Default Web Site/TestApp' /section:system.webServer/security/authorization
```

i get this result:

```
PS C:\windows\system32\inetsrv> .\appcmd list config 'Default Web Site/TestApp' /section:system.webServer/security/authorization 

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authorization>
      <add accessType="Allow" users="User1,User2" roles="Admin,Guest" />
      <add accessType="Allow" users="User3" roles="" />
    </authorization>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But i can't figure out how to return 'true' or 'false' if $user is already present or not. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select-Xml` to grab the add objects from the xml.  Then you can check for your user, role, or user/role combination.  I demonstrate this with the following function

```
Function Check-UserOrRoleExists {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $User,
        $Role,
        $AppAuthConfig
        
        )
        $authorizations = Select-Xml -Content $AppAuthConfig -XPath '//authorization//add' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node
        
        $result = if ($User -and $Role) {
            $authorizations | Where-Object { ($_.users -match $User + '(?:,|$)') -and ($_.roles -match $Role + '(?:,|$)') }
        }
        elseif ($User) {
            $authorizations | Where-Object { ($_.users -match $User + '(?:,|$)') }
        }
        elseif ($Role) {
            $authorizations | Where-Object { $_.roles -match $Role + '(?:,|$)' }
        }
        
        [bool]$result
    }
```

Usage and Output

```
# Capture response from appcmd
    $response = .\appcmd list config 'Default Web Site/TestApp' /section:system.webServer/security/authorization

PS > Check-UserOrRoleExists -AppAuthConfig $response -User User1

True
PS > Check-UserOrRoleExists -AppAuthConfig $response -User User4

False
PS > Check-UserOrRoleExists -AppAuthConfig $response -User User3 -Role admin

False
PS > Check-UserOrRoleExists -AppAuthConfig $response -User User1 -Role admin

True
PS > Check-UserOrRoleExists -AppAuthConfig $response -Role admin            

True
```